# SASS: Compass isn't outputing my code properly?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I have the following transition code.

```
  @include transition(transform 0.5s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.5s ease-in-out);
```

When it gets spit out as CSS, I get something like:

```
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s ease-in-out box-shadow 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.5s ease-in-out box-shadow 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out box-shadow 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out box-shadow 0.5s ease-in-out;
```

I am missing a comma between 2 transitions so the browser renders them invalid.
What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is a Compass bug.
https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/1450

and it has been fixed on GitHub.

I am new with GitHub. 
So how do I go about updating my Compass?

---

**Upgrade Compass**

Check version
https://rubygems.org/gems/compass

Stable Compass:

```
gem update compass
```

Cutting edge Compass:

```
gem uninstall compass
gem install compass --pre
```

Comment: @agconti I got an error for that. There is no valid gem call "compass-update"

Comment: Yup, I know that work. That gem update compass won't work for --pre version. So it seems that the solution is to uninstall compass and reinstall --pre. All versions are displayed here. https://rubygems.org/gems/compass